# links to current and previous pages not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

## error

```
undefined method `current' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #28):
```

## code

```
 25: </tr>
 26: <% end %>
 27: </table>
 28: <%= link_to 'Previous page',{:page => @post_pages.current.previous } if    @post_pages.current.previous %>
 29: <%= link_to 'Next page',{:page => @post_pages.current.next } if @post_pages.current.next  %>
 30: <br />
```

## controller code

```
  # GET /posts
  # GET /Posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @posts }
    end
  end
```

Comment: What does your controller code look like where you set the value of `@post_pages`?

Comment: i generated the scaffold and its suppose to generate the @post_pages automatically , right ??

Comment: Not as far as I know, unless you're using some kind of extra pagination gem that says it will give you a `@post_pages` variable.  As far as I can tell from the controller code, you only have `@posts` to play with in your view.  What led you to expect you would also have `@post_pages`?

Comment: but after that @post_pages.current.previous i have used the if condition , isnt it supposed to take care of it
 what am i supposed to do now , even if i create this variable how am i supposed to create its current , pervious and next methods?

Comment: Well, if your goal is to paginate through your posts, why not try out the [will_paginate gem](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) as your next step.  Have a look and see if it does what you want cause it's a great gem and very easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the will paginate gem, as one of the above commenters mentions.

Then you'd implement it like this (these are examples from the gem page...):

```
## perform a paginated query:
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])

# or, use an explicit "per page" limit:
Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)

## render page links in the view:
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

In your specific example, it would be something like this:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @posts }
  end
end
```

And your view would be simpler:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

You'd need to work through some specifics but it makes things a lot easier.

Here are 2 Railscasts that will give you some background:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax/

http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax